# mongodb treating none value as -1

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

mongodb treating none value as -1? Below code only shows data with value of 1 up where I also have 0 or null or none value.

```
case Some("hideUrX") => q = q ++ MongoDBObject("$and" -> List(MongoDBObject("ratings.rating" -> MongoDBObject("$ne" -> -1)), MongoDBObject("ratings.userId" -> userId)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fixed this by using $nin and with my expect value

```
MongoDBObject("ratings.rating" -> MongoDBObject("$in" -> Array(null,0,1)))
```